# Is this considered a Random sample?

Tags: anova, nonparametric

The Department has an online system whereby students can voluntary sign up to take part in lab studies to earn credits towards their coursework. Students have to check this online system frequently to see if they are interested in participating in any of the listed studies. Also they visit that online system to register to participate in the studies if they need additional credit.

As a researcher, I when I log into that online system database, I contact all the students  who have expressed interest to invite them to my lab. Out of 400 students, only 50 students show up for the study.

Is this regarded as a random sample?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

This is opportunity or convenience sampling and is not random.

You might see [wikipedia on sampling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sampling_%28statistics%29#Accidental_sampling)